# How can I create a column that always points to the same hyperlink and is not editable

Tags: custom-field-types

Working with foundation 2010.

I'm trying to create an admin configurable read-only hyperlink field.

I'd like a column type where I can specify the url and description (in the content type administration), but when it's used in a list on the site, those values are read-only.

How can I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to create a [custom field type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg132914.aspx)

For what you need the code will be very easy to produce.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to create a column that is going to be static, and the same for all items in the list? What a waste!
Instead, it would make more sense to store the link in a separate location, and append it to the rendered views.

Answer (score 0):

You should get most of your answer from here as it goes into detail with examples:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee524076.aspx

and

http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/blogs/GetThePoint/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=58

hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the links, although they don't seem to apply
1) - It's not external data, just a column I want to contain a link to a specific list
2) I only want the one field/column read only, not the whole item, and I can't restrict to 'owner/creator'

Comment: He meant field not the whole content type chap.